# Avoiding a for loop in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table that I need to join with itself and find the missing items and I'm stuck. Maybe it's just an inexperience issue, but I seem to only be able to think in terms of a loop to accomplish what I want.

Essentially the table is as follows:

```
    packageID     Server
      1           baseline
      2           baseline
      3           baseline
      1           server1
      3           server1
      2           server2
      3           server2
```

What I'm hoping to accomplish is to find what packages are missing from each server. I can get this on a server by server basis like so:

```
    SELECT base.*, ISNULL(dp.server,'server1') as Server
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT packageID FROM DB1
          WHERE server = 'baseline') base
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         (SELECT packageID, server FROM DB1
          WHERE server = 'server1') dp
   WHERE dp.server IS NULL
```

Which gives me what I want on an individual server basis.

```
    packageID     Server
       2          server1
```

How would I accomplish getting a list of each package a particular server is missing from the baseline?

Comment: How dow you know how many servers are? Don't you need a servers table?

Comment: I could get a list of servers into a view by getting a distinct server from that list if that would help in a solution?

Comment: My point is, what if one server has no packages deployed? Then it wouldn't appear at all, nor in the table nor in the view, but you will still need to know they are missing.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. In my particular case I'm not worried that as it can't be a deployment server without hosting at least 1 package.

Comment: can't you just make a view which has `(SELECT DISTINCT packageID FROM DB1 WHERE server = 'baseline') base LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT DISTINCT server FROM ` DB1/View(as you had said) .... and then just get those records which are in this `VIEW` but not in `DB1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a view with the list of SERVERS, and take it as pseudo-SQL as I can't test it, something like this should work I think...

```
SELECT base.packageID, servers.server, 
             (SELECT count(*) 
                FROM base AS b1
               WHERE b1.packageId = base.packageId
                 AND b1.server    = servers.server) deployed
  FROM base, servers
 WHERE base.server = 'baseline'
   AND deployed = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! If you wouldn't mind, could you explain the deployed piece a little bit, I'm not sure I understand logically how that is working.

Comment: Sure, it basically checks for every baseline package checks every server and counts the number occurrences in base table (which would always be 0 or 1), if there is no occurrence (0 in deployed) then you know is missing.

Comment: Thank you again. I felt dirty just doing this in a loop in powershell.

Comment: No problems, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this scripts,

```
      DECLARE @DB1 TABLE
(
    PackageID INT
    ,Server VARCHAR(50)
)


INSERT INTO @DB1 VALUES(1,'baseline')
INSERT INTO @DB1 VALUES(2,'baseline')
INSERT INTO @DB1 VALUES(3,'baseline')
INSERT INTO @DB1 VALUES(1,'server1')
INSERT INTO @DB1 VALUES(3,'server1')
INSERT INTO @DB1 VALUES(2,'server2')
INSERT INTO @DB1 VALUES(3,'server2')

;WITH CTE_Package AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT PackageID 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by PackageID) AS ID
    FROM @DB1
)
,CTE_Servers AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Server 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by PackageID) AS ID
    FROM @DB1
)
,CTE_Server_Packages AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT P.PackageId, S.Server   
    FROM CTE_Servers S
    CROSS JOIN CTE_Package P    
)
SELECT Server, PackageID
FROM 
(
    SELECT SP.Server, SP.PackageID , D.PackageID [ActualPackage], D.Server [ActualServer]
    FROM CTE_Server_Packages SP
    LEFT JOIN @DB1 D
            ON D.PackageID = SP.PackageID
            AND D.Server = SP.Server
) AS TEMP
WHERE TEMP.ActualServer IS NULL
```